# How to create an Event on a Variable Change inside an Object Class

Tags: java, events, class, variables, listener

I am stuck on implementing something along the lines of the following simple example-

```
public class SimpleClass
{
    int test=0;
    AnotherClass anotherClass= new AnotherClass();

    public SimpleClass()
    {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
        SimpleClass simpleClass = new SimpleClass();
    }
}

public class AnotherClass
{
    int value=5;

    .
    .
    .
}
```

I would like to make 'test' (say) increment by 1 every time the value in 'anotherClass' changes (anotherClass might be getting information in from a datafeed or something like that).  All of the oracle event docs I can find refer to swing components.  I have found similar requests for help on this online, but the answers didn't seem to solve this problem.

Thanks for any help you can provide!
C

==================================================================================

Addition- (sorry, it wouldn't fit in the response-comment boxes)

Thanks for your suggestions.  But if I have a class A which has another class B sitting in it as a field, and I want to (1) listen for changes in a field of class B (say int var), and (2) detect these changes at the level of class A have the resulting event fire a method in class A, it is not obvious to me that this approach will work.

For if I put my listener in class A, I can't specify to listen for changes in "B.var" from here.  Conversely, if I put my listener in class B, which is a field of class A, then it will be able to detect changes in var, but how would I able to cause this to fire and make changes in class A, because B sits in class A as a field, and isn't "aware" of class A's existence?

One solution would be to incorporate all of the fields and methods of B into A.  However, ultimately I would like to have B as a static class and have many different A's, with each A listening to slightly different events in B.  The picture I have in mind in my head is of lots of different people listening to the ratio, which is broadcasting lots of different words.  Each person is watching for his own particular word to come from the radio, and each time their word occurs, they put a check on their wall (or increment some field they have..)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Think about the way this problem is solved in Swing. This is the observer pattern.

```
class A implements ChangeListener{

    private B aB;

    public A(){
        aB = new B();
        aB.addListener(this);
    }

    public void thingyChanged(String newThingy){
        System.out.println("Thingy changed to:" + newThingy);
    }
}

class B {

    private Collection<ChangeListener> listeners = new LinkedList<ChangeListener>();

    public B(){}

    public void addListener(ChangeListener listener){
        listeners.add(listener)
    }

    public void changeThingy(String newThingyVal){
        doSomething(newThingyVal);
        for(ChangeListener listener:listeners){
            listener.thingyChanged(newThingyVal);
        }
    }

}

interface ChangeListener{
    public void thingChanged(String newThingy);
}
```

Note: Didn't compile this or anything.

This is called an observer pattern. You're using an interface to create a callback.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I replied in an edit of the original question.

Answer (score 0):

An option could be to implement your class as a JavaBean and then implement a PropertyChangeListener

Take a look at a quick overview of the technique.

http://www.kodejava.org/examples/343.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, I have replied in the original post because I didn't have enough space.